# A Ten letter Word

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I am a 10 letter Word.
>
> I have every **vowels** in me.
>
> If you take 4th, 8th, 9th and 10th letters gives **Prison**.
>
> The 3rd, 4th, 5th, 7th and 10th letters means **Grade**.

Who am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is

> DISCOURAGE

If you take 4th,8th,9th and 10th letters gives Prison

> DIS**C**OUR**AGE** (CAGE)

The 3rd,4th,5th,7th and 10th letters means Grade

> DI**SCO**U**R**AG**E** (SCORE)

Comment: You beat me to the second! I was just finishing my last spoiler when you posted it :x

Comment: Maybe next time @Radhato! :)